# How to route log messages based on category using log4j2.xml

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am after routing log messages based on category using log4j2.xml. 
I found below link but not sure how to achieve it
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/logger-component-reference#configuring-custom-logging-settings

Can someone please provide an example config for log4j2.xml.

Below is config from my log4j2.xml

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="file" 
fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs
${sys:file.separator}splunktest.log" 
             filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}splunktest-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="splunk"   
 fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs
${sys:file.separator}ForSplunk.log" 
             filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}ForSplunk-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<AsyncRoot level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </AsyncRoot>

    <AsyncLogger name="test" level="INFO" category="splunk">
        <AppenderRef ref="splunk" />
    </AsyncLogger>
```

Logger output for category APP and splunk. In this case i want category splunk logger message to go to file ForSplunk.log.

- [[splunktest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] APP: Start
  Logger

  - [[splunktest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] splunk:
    End Logger

Answer (score 0):

@user3366906 We had used logging category in our project.

You need to specify some value to category field and that same value should be specified in a cloudHub logging.

Comment: I have added config from my log4j2.xml now